# Make Ubuntu as a server and Windows their client

Tags: server, windows

I want to add Windows user to Ubuntu and implement some restrictive policies to Windows user. Just like making Ubuntu or RHEL as a server and Windows as client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to install and configure Samba PDC or configure LDAP.

Comment: ok i have configured LDAP on rhel 6.0 but how to configure it in windows....? Please help me..

Comment: ok Samba PDC worked...but can you tell how to set permissions to particular users..